# Is it possible to return value from PHP to Ajax after error 500?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This Ajax is sending some data to php file and getting back the response that is showed in my html. Everything is working fine but sometimes I have been getting Error 500 response from php file. I know why and it is ok because as you can see after error 500 I'm calling the Ajax function again.

My question is. Is it possible to return from php file also some data after getting error 500? By data I mean variable returned from php file when the error occured.

```
function tr() {
 var vysledok = document.getElementById('vysledok_body');
 var text= document.getElementById('source').value;
 var languageFrom = document.getElementById("src").value;
 var languageTo = document.getElementById("dst").value;
 vysledok.innerHTML="";
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open('GET', "https://.... someurl.php?
 from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + text, true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      console.log(obj.ip);
      vysledok.innerHTML = "<p class='bdr'>"+obj.text+"</p>";
  }
if(xmlhttp.status == 500) {
    //console.log('nejde');
    tr();
  }
}
 };
 xmlhttp.send(null);       
}
```

Comment: yes u can use it make sure u add tr(); assign to variable 
Also in `200 response condition` set response *return true*.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, and what are the potential causes of the 500?

Comment: @RossWilson Php 7, I send some data to external server and wait for response. Sometimes is the url blocked and then I get error 500.

Comment: Do you know what is causing the 500 error though?

Comment: @RossWilson as I said. Sometime is my URL blocked by external server and then I get error 500.

Comment: So how would you be able to catch that error in your php file in order to adapt the response?

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what is causing the error. What you can do is catching the error if it is caused by an exception and in the catch block handle it the way you want.

For example you can return a value in the catch block and set the response code to 500 from PHP.

If however your script crashes with a fatal error that is not handled you can't change the return value there, but could still configure your web server to deliver a custom error page that can be read by your JS.